# Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Projects

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, I made a jar out of a project P2 which was dependent on P1. This jar is stored in the C:\Projects folder. I get the error when I try to run it using Eclipse> Run > external tools. Please tell me how i can fix it and how these things work so that i can understand why the problem occurred.

My guess is that I made a mistake while setting the options to run this Jar using external tools > external tools configurations.

My system - windows 7, 64-bit.

Comment: Try another way to deal with the dependency between two projects, use the project tab of the build path dialog. Run the project normally and eclipse do the works properly.

Comment: I am not able to understand what you said. What do i do with the projects tab ? What does this mean - "run the project normally" ? 
Please help me to make this thing work properly.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the jar to your build path.

Right click the project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path... -> Libraries -> Add External JARs...

However I haven't use `run-> external tools` yet and so it may not solve your problem. The above solution should allow to get your project running with "Run As".

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are trying to run a jar using eclipse, and your jar needs that dependent jar P1 to run. Change your project P2 manifest file to include jar P1 as its dependency. It should work.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi ! How do i change the manifest of P2 to make it work ? Can you help me with that ? 
Thanks